# Why does onClick event does not work if outerHTML is used?

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog, outerhtml

Sample code below:

```
serviceQuerySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                        
                        if(ownerIdNo === doc.data().shooter_id){
                            const servViewButton = document.createElement("button");
                            servViewButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
                            servViewButton.style.marginRight = "5px";
                            servViewButton.style.border = "0";
                            servViewButton.style.background = "transparent";

                            servViewButton.onclick = async function() {

                                alert("wow");
                                console.error();
                            }

                            const servArrItem = ` · ${doc.data().name} ${servViewButton.outerHTML} ${'<br>'}`;
                            servArr += servArrItem;
        
                        }

                    });
```

As you can see here, I have an onclick event assigned to servViewButton and use servViewButton.outerHTML to display it next to the document name and add it to an Array but it seems like the onclick event is not working. The alert message is not prompting even after I click the button.

tried using addEventListener but the alert message still doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong here? Please help.

Comment: Because `onxxxx` properties are not reflected to corresponding `onxxxx` attributes. Don't create HTML elements from markup strings, use DOM methods to create and insert elements instead.

Comment: to expand on what Teemu said, when you extract the .outerHTML from your button, you lose all of the information on that button that isn't contained in the HTML, including the listeners. you'll want to insert the button into the DOM with appendChild or similar

Answer (score 0):

Use addEventListener instead of click method and don’t use an async function.
Try this:

```
servViewButton.addEventListener(“click”, () => { alert(“wow”); console.error(“error”)}
```

Comment: Thank you but it still doesn't work any other ideas?